# Querying DocumentDB for a list of propertiers using Linq's Select

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

Using Azure's DocumentDb and the .NET API, I have the following method which works great for retrieving lists of entire documents:

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {            
        IDocumentQuery<T> query = _Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_DatabaseId, _Collection),
            new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 })
            .Where(predicate)
            .AsDocumentQuery();

        List<T> results = new List<T>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var item = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
            results.AddRange(item);
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Now, I don't always want to return the entire document (especially considering the DocumentDb RU pricing model), so I thought I should be able to add a .Select projection like so:

```
 public async Task<List<TResult>> GetItemsAsync<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> select)
        {
            IDocumentQuery<TResult> query = _Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_DatabaseId, _Collection),
                new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 })
                .Where(predicate)
                .Select(select)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

            List<TResult> results = new List<TResult>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var item = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<TResult>();
                results.AddRange(item);
            }

            return results;
        }
```

Usage:

```
var rez = await _docs.GetItemsAsync<ApolloAssetDoc, Guid?>(x => x.MyVal == 5, x => x.ID);
```

But the second method always return 0 results.  Obviously I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Any idea what the correct way to return a list of either dynamic objects for queries where more than one property is selected (eg `"SELECT d.id, d.MyVal FROM Items d WHERE d.DocType=0"`)or a simple list where only a single property is selected (eg `"SELECT d.id FROM Items d WHERE d.DocType=0"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could repro the issue, if there is no `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]` for **ID** property in the entity Class. If it is not included, please have a try to use the following code:

```
public class ApolloAssetDoc
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string MyVal { get; set; }

    }
```

**Note**: The field is **case sensitive**.

Comment: Interesting!  I did have that property defined, but I had it defined in an "ICosmosDocument" document interface.  I didn't realize the JsonProperty mapping attribute couldn't be applied in the interface!  Probably applies to any Attribute? Thanks for the assist!